# Filemaker CWP safety

Tags: filemaker

In developing a CWP, is there a way to use the record id and mod id to enusure the record has not been modified since to provide a fallback instead of a race condition if 2 updates are sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modification id is the amount of times the record has been modified. using FX, you can do a `->addDbParam('-mkodid',$modid);` or a `->SetModID($modid);` and Filemaker will compare this number, and if there has been any modifications; it will error out with an errorCode of 306.